# Is it wise to connect a (non-latching) relay's NC in parallel with another same relay's NO to achieve a switchable NC/NO output?

Tags: relay

[image]

As shown in the image, when the two toggle switches are closed,
will the output be NC because top relay gives NO and bottom gives NC?

Is it okay to wire like this, if not what are the possible alternative solutions?
Thank you for your time.

*Truth table (for OP to complete).*

```
A    B    Z
Off  Off  ? 
Off  On   ?
On   Off  ?
On   On   ?
```

Comment: You haven't really described what problem you're trying to solve - so it's difficult to come up with possible alternative solutions ...

Comment: Hi, I want to have an output terminal connected in parallel to NO port and NC port, when both is NC, the ouput is NC, when both is NO, the output is NO, and when either NC, the output is NC. Thanks @brhans

Comment: I've added a truth table for you to edit. Tips: We use the word "contact" rather than "port". The output won't be "NC" or "NO"; it will be "on" or "off". Label your switches and label the relays to make it easy to discuss them.

Answer (score 2):

This circuit is a relay-based gate giving :

A + NOT(B)

It is ok to wire it like that. But do not forget to add flyback diodes on relays coils.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly that you want the output contacts to close only when both relays are energised then yes your proposal is fine.  You could also use the first relay to switch the coil of the second - this would mean that the load current would only pass through one set of contact s and not two.